# Idiomatic way to conditionally process IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, io, conditional-statements, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a little shell script in Haskell which can take an optional argument. However, if the argument is not present, I'd like to get a line from stdin in which to ask for a value.

What would be the idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Char (toLower)
import IO (hFlush, stdout)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          -- here should be some sort of branching logic that reads
          -- the prompt unless `length args == 1`
          name <- lowerCase <$> readPrompt "Gimme arg: "
          putStrLn name

lowerCase = map toLower

flushString :: String -> IO ()
flushString s = putStr s >> hFlush stdout

readPrompt :: String -> IO String
readPrompt prompt = flushString prompt >> getLine
```

Oh, and if there's a way to do it with something from `Control.Applicative` or `Control.Arrow` I'd like to know. I've become quite keen on these two modules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          name <- lowerCase <$> case args of
            [arg] -> return arg
            _     -> readPrompt "Gimme arg: "
          putStrLn name
```

Comment: I like it. It's pretty clean. The patterns in the case expression are non-exhaustive, but was easily fixable.

Comment: @Ionuț G. Stan: I just translate your meaning one by one. Making the pattern exhaustive would make my example less clean.

Comment: I'd put `lowerCase <$>` in front of the `case args of` so that the command line arg would also be lowercased. Also, you could just match `[arg]` and `_` (instead of `[]`) to stay closer to the requested behavior.

Comment: @Dan: Incorporated these advises.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't fit your specific use case, but the question title made me think immediately of `when` from `Control.Monad`. Straight from [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:when):

> `when :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()`
>
> Conditional execution of monadic expressions.

Example:

```
main = do args <- getArgs
          -- arg <- something like what FUZxxl did..
          when (length args == 1) (putStrLn $ "Using command line arg: " ++ arg)
          -- continue using arg...
```

You can also use `when`'s cousin `unless` in similar fashion.

Comment: I thought about `when` too. The issue was that I needed some sort of it/then/else instead of just an if/then. Also, when doesn't return anything. I would have had to "assign to a variable" inside it, which probably means using the State monad. Not so sure though. Thanks for the answer.